# Microsoft.Synchronization SyncAgent crashing after upgrade to VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I have set up a project in Visual Studio 2008 using .net 3.5 that has a component that synchronizes data from my sqlserver down to the client sqlce database (SDF file). Everything was working fine until I decided to upgrade the project to Visual Studio 2010, and now the following code crashes:

```
 try
        {
            MySyncAgent syncAgent = new MySyncAgent(filter);
            SyncStatistics syncStats = syncAgent.Synchronize(); //this crashes
        }
```

The exception I get is:EXCEPTION MESSAGE = [OBJECT REFERENCE NOT SET TO AN INSTANCE OF AN OBJECT.] : STACKTRACE = [   AT SYSTEM.DATA.SQLSERVERCE.SQLCECHANGETRACKING.UPGRADEPUBLICTRACKING(STRING CONNECTIONSTRING)
   AT MICROSOFT.SYNCHRONIZATION.DATA.SQLSERVERCE.SQLCECLIENTSYNCPROVIDER.PERFORMUPGRADEIFNECESSARY()
   AT MICROSOFT.SYNCHRONIZATION.DATA.SQLSERVERCE.SQLCECLIENTSYNCPROVIDER.BEGINTRANSACTION(SYNCSESSION SYNCSESSION)
   AT MICROSOFT.SYNCHRONIZATION.SYNCAGENT.DATASYNCHRONIZE()
   AT MICROSOFT.SYNCHRONIZATION.SYNCAGENT.SYNCHRONIZE()

What am I missing?

For reference, my MySyncAgent class constructor looks like this:

```
 public class MySyncAgent : Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncAgent
{
 public MySyncAgent(string filter)
    {
        this.InitializeSyncProviders(filter);
        this.InitializeSyncTables();
    }
}
```

Comment: So nice of you to capitalize the entire stack trace for us. You really shouldn't have.

Comment: Have you checked your ConnectionString(s) ? Ie can you access the SqlCe Db aside from the Sync fx?

Comment: yes, can open the sdf aside from the sync issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try upgrading your SQL CE to 3.5 SP2.

Comment: can you verify if the Project References to the Sync framework assemblies are pointing to the 2.1 version?

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem!